# Unable to set the caption or value of a HTML button element to the degree C symbol using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

An ESP8266 is used to dynamically generate a webpage that includes buttons. The Javascript is embedded in c.  The Label (aka caption aka value) of the button toggles depending on the mode.

The code that sets the button caption looks like this

```
document.getElementByID('idUnits').value='&#176;C'
```

When using chrome's development tools and viewing the generated html it looks like

```
<input type="button" value="&#176;C" id="idUnits" onclick="dendbuttons(this.id);">
```

If I hover over the value and right click "edit attribute" it shows `&#176;C` however if I hover over and "Edit as HTML" it gives me this to edit which includes an unwanted `amp;`

```
<input type="button" value="&amp;#176;C" id="idUnits" onclick="dendbuttons(this.id);">
```

if I remove the amp; while editing (in Chrome's development tool)  the button html displays the correct symbol.

Why does amp; get added to the value of the button.  How do I encourage it not to do so.  I am using a similar technique to dynamically update other html elements with the degree symbol without issue.  Only when attempting to do this with the "Button" element do I have issues.

Comment: I am not clear what is  the problem, but `&amp;` is the HTML encoded for `&` (ampersand)...

Comment: The problem is when I set the value of the button to "&#176;C" it does NOT render as  °C it renders as &#176;C and on closer inspection the html code has gained a amp; that I did not want

Comment: *The Javascript is embedded in c* - show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the `value` property does not parse your HTML. So the htmlEntity (degrees symbol) string will not yet be seen as one. Although when using "Edit as HTML" you'll suddenly parse everything that you've selected as HTML, including your htmlEntity string.

I would recommend you using a button element instead.

```
<button type="button" id="idUnits" onclick="dendbuttons(this.id);"></button>
```

And add the htmlEntity with the `.innerHTML` setter which will parse your string as HTML and thus decodes the symbol and renders it.

```
document.getElementByID('idUnits').innerHTML = '&#176;C';
```

Comment: I tried to upvote this but I have limited reputation. I had completely missed the fact that my element was "input" and not "button".  Changing this and using .innerHTML  (which I had tried previously) solved my issues.  Thankyou for you suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use HTML entities inside JS strings as they won't be parsed, but you can use the [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) to represent them with their Unicode code.

So, how do you get the Unicode code of `°`...?

One option is to just [look it up](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/degree-sign/).

The other one, if you can type or copy-paste the original character from somewhere else, is to get it using [`String.prototype.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), which returns the UTF-16 code unit (decimal) at the given index, and [`Number.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString), using its `radix` parameter to convert that decimal to hexadecimal:

```
'°'.charCodeAt(0); // 176
'°'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); // "b0"
```

So, using the `\xXX` notation, your code should be:

```js
document.getElementById('idUnits').value='\xb0C';
```

```html
<input type="button" id="idUnits">
```

Lastly, rather than using two characters `° + C = °C`, you might want to use [this other specific character: `℃`](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/degree-celsius/).

Same thing here, but using the `\uXXXX` notation instead:

```
'℃'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16); // "2103"
```

So then the code would look like this:

```js
// Note the escape notation here is different, as 
// explained in MDN's documentation:
document.getElementById('idUnits').value='\u2103';
```

```html
<input type="button" id="idUnits">
```

Comment: @Ornea You can vote as many answers as you want, but you can only mark one as "Accepted". You should be able to upvote now, you need a reputation score of at least 25.

Comment: This is really cool, I never knew this is how you do that. Could you explain what `.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)` actually does and how it gets that result? Hats off to you @Danziger

Comment: Thanks.   I am making a bit of a mess here with my comments it seems.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Please, take a look at the updated answer. In short, `.chartCodeAt(0)` gives you the decimal Unicode code at index 0 and `.toString(16)` converts that to hexadecimal.

Comment: @Danziger thanks for the detailed response. I feel I have learned something today.